# How to find the column label by description value?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a table that is dynamically generated, i want to find the sum column that exists at the end of the SUM row. How can I found that column ?

here's my jquery so far:

```
keyup: function (e) {

            // get the level
            var level = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

            // this = all columns in the row
            var inputValue = $(this).find('input').val();

            // get account nr from first column
            var account = $(this).closest('tr').children().eq(0).text();

            // get all elements with the same level id
            var elements = $('tr[id=' + level + ']'); //.find('*').filter(function () {
```

here is my table

```
<table id="table">
    <!-- 
        row is dyanmically looped and tr id can be whatever in that format 
        and has many of the same id
    -->
    <tr id="1-2-2">
          <td>test</td>
          <td><%= x.Description %></td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td><label name="account-<%= rad.Konto %>"></label></td>
        </tr>
```

When the Description is SUM then I want to get the label from the last column on the same row and update it with new value that is entered in the keydown function.

Comment: you can give class to your sum column

Comment: +1 @rajeshkakawat, I was writing exactly the same: `<td class="<%= x.Description %>"><%= x.Description %></td>` and then select with jQuery `$(".sum")`

Comment: hi, rajesh! Thx for your feedback!
problem is that i dont have  sum column, it can be sum or just description

Comment: is there something that you can use to differentiate between sum or description

Comment: well .. the only thing is the Text itself. If it starts with SUM then.
I think of this. 1. Find all rows which have id=1-2-2 then find SUM in the array, if it is founded then use .closes(tr) and get the last column with eq() but i dont know have to to that in jquery code. I have come so far so I get the list of all rows containing same row id but how can i found text starting with SUM in the array ?